# Python list has 3 elements but I can only access the last element

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am processing a POST request in a django view and am expecting a list of strings in one of the dictionary elements.  I'm using Pycharm to debug the code and I can see that in the dictionary, 3 values are returned but when I try to access that dictionary element, I can only access the last item in the list.

[image: Code from Pycharm]

I'm hoping it's a typecast issue of some sort perhaps?

The filepond dictionary is a 3rd party java library I'm using so I have no control over how it gets POSTed back to django.

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.
[You should not post code as an image because:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
my_list = self.request.POST.getlist('filepond')
```

Read more about it in [Django's Official Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist).